# Catching an exception when a user inputs an integer while using a Scanner object

Tags: java, string, exception, input, integer

I'm trying to catch an exception when the user enters any integer in the Scanner. I understand that using a String item = scan.nextLine() will allow for any input to be made including integers. I created a custom exception to catch the number 1. But what happens if the user inputs 999 or any other integer. How can I catch those other integers as part of the exception?

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class ExampleOne {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TestCustomException {
    
    System.out.println("Please enter any word:");
    
    try {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String item = scan.nextLine();
        if (item.contains("1")) {
            throw new TestCustomException();
        } 
    }catch (TestCustomException e) {
        System.out.println("A problem occured:  " + e);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Thank you for using my application.");
    
}
```

}

public class TestCustomException extends Exception {

```
TestCustomException (){
    super("You can't enter any number value here");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter any word:");
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String item = scan.nextLine();

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+.?[0-9]+");
            Matcher isNum = pattern.matcher(item);

            if (isNum.matches()) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("A problem occured:  " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for using my application.");

    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation,  to understand better.

Comment: Great! So this works how I want it to work to accept only words and throw an exception when the user enters only numbers. Note: with Patter pattern = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+.?[0-9]+") it doesn't throw an exception with single digits. So I modified the line with: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+"); and now it works perfectly! Thank you @MakerStack!